# SQLAlchemy update objects tree

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I'm trying to build a tree of objects. The class looks like this:

```
class Node(BaseModel, db.Model):
    '''Node model'''
    __tablename__ = 'network_nodes'
    id = Column(String(10), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(String(10), ForeignKey('network_nodes.id'))
    parent = relationship("Node", foreign_keys=[parent_id], lazy='dynamic')
    left_id = Column(String(10), ForeignKey('network_nodes.id'))
    left = relationship("Node", foreign_keys=[parent_id], lazy='dynamic')
    right_id = Column(String(10), ForeignKey('network_nodes.id'))
    right = relationship("Node", foreign_keys=[parent_id], lazy='dynamic')
```

Whenever new leaf is added this code is executed:

```
node.left_id = element_id
left = Node(id=element_id, parent_id=node.id)
db.session.add(left)
```

And at some point I commit all changes with `db.session.commit()`. At the `commit()` point I see dirty and new objects in session. But commit fails with error:

> (MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`network_nodes`, CONSTRAINT `network_nodes_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`left_id`) REFERENCES `network_nodes` (`id`))')
> [SQL: UPDATE network_nodes SET left_id=%s, right_id=%s WHERE network_nodes.id = %s]
> [parameters: ('S5837124', 'S5839010', 'S5832131')]

I assume dirty objects are committed before new ones. Therefore `left_id` refers to not yet existing record.

How can I make new object committed before dirty ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make new object committed before dirty ones?

You could add all the objects, flush the new ones, and then commit the whole batch:

```py
    left = Node(id=element_id, parent_id=node.id)
    session.add(left)
    node.left_id = element_id
    
    session.flush(session.new)
    session.commit()
```

Comment: Does it mean I have to flush session every time I add an object? I'm adding up to 2000 objects per transaction. Wouldn't such flushing affect performance?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you. Second option I like more but unfortunately objects created later depend on objects created earlier and I end up with same problem. So I had to use first option and flush session after every object creation.